# Удаление слов/букв на входных данных в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача: написать программу, которая удаляет первый и крайний элемент строки из входных данных на выходе. Т.е. как я понял, программа должна удалять автоматом первый и крайний индекс массива. Но сначала преобразовать строку в массив. У меня выдает ошибки разного вида при написании, как бы я не пробовал.
Пользовался:

```
A = input("Введите предложение: ").split()
A = list(A)
A.pop(0)
A.pop(max)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/uuu.py", line 5, in <module>
    A.pop(max)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку?

Comment: О каких ошибках речь? Показанный здесь код работает.

Comment: прописывает это: builtin_function_or_method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: используйте срезы print('123456789'[1:-1])

Comment: извиняюсь, только начал изучать этот язык. как конкретно и где правильно будет прописать срезы?

Comment: «прописывает это» — где? Показанный здесь код не может прописывать такое

Comment: В скобках инпут прописал "Введите предложение", так по задаче было указано. При выполнении программы ввожу рандомное предложение и после выдаёт такую ошибку. Т.е. с предложением не работает

Comment: Обновите текст вопроса, показав, как прописали, и полный текст ошибки

Comment: "где правильно будет прописать срезы?" Берете книшку по питону. На худой конец спросите у гугла. Иначе вам не когда не познать пайтон.

Comment: @СергейШ да в гугле уже два часа с этим кодом вожусь. хотелось посоветоваться или чтоб ткнули носом. на форум зарегистрировался от отчаяния)) По программе изучения пайтона остановился на циклах и массивах. Срезы ещё не изучал, поэтому и уточнил

Comment: `A.pop(max)` — а вот эта строчка явно намекает, что вы вообще не понимаете что пишете. Так что действительно стоит взять «книшку по питону»

Comment: @andreymal , пробовал разными методами указать последний индекс для удаления. но все не канают. возможно не в этом дело, не могу разобраться

Comment: Если вы прочитаете [документацию метода pop](https://pythonz.net/references/named/list.pop/), то узнаете, что он по умолчанию удаляет последний элемент, так что не надо прописывать вообще никакой индекс

Comment: @andreymal , спасибо огромное за терпение и ответ. уже прочел и понял свою ошибку. еще раз спасибо

Comment: @Илья хорошим тоном так же будет оставить ответ на свой собственный вопрос, с разьяснением, что за метод, в чем была ошибка и конечное решение. И вам будет полезно разобраться более детально и запомнить.